# Aurelia silently fails when there is no <template> wrapper

Tags: aurelia

When there is no `<template> ... </template>` wrapper in the view, Aurelia fails with the following error:

> Template markup must be wrapped in a  element e.g. <template> <!-- markup here --> </template>

This works for example in the [skeleton app](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation).

However, I have messed up something in my application and now Aurelia silently fails when there is no `<template>`, giving no clue what happens. I have absolutely no idea where to look for the issue. I could not reproduce the minimal example either.

I have `.developmentLogging()` configured. When I am trying to load a page without the `<template>` wrapper (provided that the app is bootstrapped already), there are no new log entries in the console.

Do you have any suggestions what I might have broken?

Comment: If you install the skeleton again and import your project it should work. I have no idea why it would just stop logging this type of errors. Do you get the other dev logs still?

Comment: I actually saw this behavior in one of my applications the other day. I just wrapped the code in a try catch with a debugger on the catch function as a bandaid. I don't think I updated Aurelia, so it might be a Chrome issue? Will keep my eyes open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a result of `aurelia-logging` `1.1.0` upgrade.

See the [related issue](https://github.com/aurelia/logging/issues/29) I have created.